# WPF boolean column checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I want to change the boolean checkbox of the "EstBonClient" cell in my Datagrid to a specific color. If the checkbox is checked the background color of the cell will be green and if the checkbox is not check the background color of the cell will be red. I want that the checkbox is not in the Datagrid.

Thank you guys !

[image]

Comment: Maybe try some documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Binding and Coverter are what you need.
Post `un peu de code` if you need an example

Comment: `<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>`

Its a good way to do things ?

Comment: post your Datagrid's XAML .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    >
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToTextConverter x:Key="booleanToTextConverter" />
    <local:BoolToColorConverter x:Key="booleanToColorConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Background="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource booleanToColorConverter}}">     
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Grid.Column="0">Check Me!</CheckBox>
        <TextBlock FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource booleanToTextConverter}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

C#:
ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    bool _isChecked;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set {
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Converters:

```
public class BooleanToTextConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? "Est Bon Client" : "Est Mauvais Client";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class BoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.GreenYellow) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkRed);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
`<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" AllowDrop="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ListeClient}"> </DataGrid>`

My DataGrid is like that. How can I implement this converters ? Thanks

Comment: I wait your answer about it

Comment: Put it between borders
`<Border Background="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource booleanToColorConverter}}">
       <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" AllowDrop="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ListeClient}"> </DataGrid>
        </Border>`